# Eclipse behaving wierdly

Tags: android, eclipse, dom, domparser

I have an application which requires dom parsing, The application is running fine on my colleagues' machines but at my machine it's throwing saxexception (unexpected token). Any idea why eclipse behaving weirdly. The following is the method how am I reading my xml file.

```
private String readFile() throws Exception{
        AssetManager assetManager = activity.getAssets();
        InputStream ims = assetManager.open("temp/MyXml.xml");

        StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while (ims.read(buffer) != -1) {
            fileContent.append(new String(buffer));
        }

        return fileContent.toString();
    }
```

The following is the method for parsing.

```
private Document getDomElement(String xml) throws Exception {

        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        // return DOM
        return doc;
    }
```

and Stack trace

```
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT 
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283): URRICANE DISH D...@2:237 in java.io.StringReader@2bdda808) 
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283):    at org.col.gsso.sap.parser.InputDataXMLParser.getDomElement(InputDataXMLParser.java:510)
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283):    at org.col.gsso.sap.parser.InputDataXMLParser.saveInputFiles(InputDataXMLParser.java:106)
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283):    at com.gps.colpal.ToPalmDownloadAsycTask.doInBackground(ToPalmDownloadAsycTask.java:103)
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283):    at com.gps.colpal.ToPalmDownloadAsycTask.doInBackground(ToPalmDownloadAsycTask.java:1)
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-05 17:16:30.200: W/System.err(12283):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-05 17:16:30.250: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12283): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: You need to show us a example of the failure

Comment: How do you get input XML, could be something to do what character sets and file encodings.